# Angular 2: Animate exterior *ngIf from within a component

Tags: angular, components, angular-ng-if

I have a component: `window-component` which is designed as a popup window that will be used all over the app.

I am using `*ngIf` on the component itself to hide and show the window. I need to do some animation with that `*ngIf`, but I need the animation to be handled within the component itself

Here is some code for clarification.

```
<window-component *ngIf="show"></window-component>
```

In other words, `window-component` needs to contain the animation within itself so that I can drop the this window anywhere in the app.

Is this possible? If so, how do you trigger internal animation with an external `*ngIf`?

Comment: So you want the *ngIf to trigger the  `* <=> void` states on the animations contained within window-component?

Comment: @Steveadoo: Yes